# Is there an identity for the partial transpose of a product of operators?

Tags: entanglement, information-theory, linear-algebra, entanglement-negativity, partial-transpose

The [partial transpose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peres%E2%80%93Horodecki_criterion) of an operator $M$ with respect to subsystem $A$ is given by
$$
M^{T_A} := \left(\sum_{abcd} M^{ab}_{cd}  \underbrace{|a\rangle \langle b| }_{A}\otimes \underbrace{|c \rangle \langle d|}_B\right)= \left(\sum_{abcd} M^{ab}_{cd}  |b\rangle \langle a| \otimes |c \rangle \langle d|\right).
$$
**Is there an identity for the partial transpose of the product of operators**,i.e.
$$
(AB)^{T_A}= \quad ?
$$
I suspect that in general $(AB)^{T_A} \neq B^{T_A} A^{T_A} $ or even $\neq A^{T_A}B^{T_A}$.

**What if $A=B$?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your suspicion is correct, even when $A=B$. Consider the Hilbert space of two qubits and let $^{T_A}$ denote the partial transpose with respect to one of them.
Suppose that

$$
A=B=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

Then

$$
A^{T_A}=B^{T_A}=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

and we see that $(AB)^{T_A} = I^{T_A} = I$, but $A^{T_A}B^{T_A} = B^{T_A}A^{T_A} = 2 A^{T_A}$ is a rank one matrix.

---

I am not aware of a simple identity connecting $(AB)^{T_A}$ and $A^{T_A}B^{T_A}$ or $B^{T_A}A^{T_A}$.

A useful computational aid is offered by tensor notation and in some cases [tensor networks](https://arxiv.org/abs/1708.00006). Note that operators such as $A$ and $B$ that act on the Hilbert space of a bipartite system can be thought of as tensors with four indices $A_{ijkl}$ and $B_{ijkl}$. Their usual matrix representation is obtained by grouping pairs of indices for example $A_{(ij)(kl)}$, $B_{(ij)(kl)}$ so that $(ij)$ indexes the rows and $(kl)$ indexes the columns. In this view partial transpose swaps the first indices from each pair $A_{(ij)(kl)}^{T_A} = A_{(kj)(il)}$. Thus

$$
(AB)_{(ij)(mn)} = \sum_{kl} A_{(ij)(kl)}B_{(kl)(mn)}\\
(AB)_{(ij)(mn)}^{T_A} = \left(\sum_{kl} A_{(ij)(kl)}B_{(kl)(mn)}\right)^{T_A} = \sum_{kl} A_{(mj)(kl)}B_{(kl)(in)}\\
(A^{T_A}B^{T_A})_{(ij)(mn)} = \sum_{kl} A^{T_A}_{(ij)(kl)}B^{T_A}_{(kl)(mn)} = \sum_{kl} A_{(kj)(il)}B_{(ml)(kn)}
$$

which shows that changing the order of matrix multiplication and partial transpose affects which elements are multiplied together.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I’ll investigate if I can progress using tensor networks, fingers crossed. Entanglement negativity seems like a not so easy to compute entanglement measure after all... I will give some time for others to contribute before assigning you the accepted answer.